# Using reduceByKey is throwing an int object is not subscriptable error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

This code gives me an "int object is not subscriptable" error despite it working for a friend of mine. The error comes in the 4th line where I'm trying to use reduceByKey to calculate the average. Why is this?

```
nonNullRDD = marchRDD.filter(lambda row: row.journal).filter(lambda row: row.abstract)
abstractRDD = nonNullRDD.map(lambda field: (field.journal, field.abstract))
splitRDD = abstractRDD.map(lambda word: (word[0], len(word[1].split(" "))))
groupedRDD = splitRDD.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1])).mapValues(lambda x: x[0]/x[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `reduceByKey` function, you provide a lambda function which acts on the value of the RDD, which is an integer from `len(word[1].split(" "))`. You tried to do `x[0]` on an integer, which results in the error you got.

I believe the RDD should be in the form `(key, (value, 1))` so that the fourth line of your code will give the average for each key. In order to achieve that, you can change the lambda function in the third line to:

```
splitRDD = abstractRDD.map(lambda word: (word[0], (len(word[1].split(" ")), 1)))
```